# External microphone has no power while connected to USB-C adapter

Tags: audio, microphone

Here's my setup:

- **Machine**: M1 Ventura
- **Microphone**: Behringer C-1U https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0588
- **Cable**: Type B to type A

Since M1 has no USB-A port, I must plug the microphone into a USB-C adapter. I can confirm that the adapter works because other connected devices are working—also, the mic and the cable work. After all, my Windows-based machine can detect the microphone.

When the microphone is plugged into the Mac machine, the microphone doesn't light up, indicating a power issue.

Here is the error I am seeing via `dmesg`:

```
AppleUSB20HubPort@01131000: AppleUSBHostPort::disconnect: persistent enumeration failures
```

**Things I tried**

- I have three different adapters, and none of them was able to make the microphone work
- I tried plugging the adapters in other ports and got the same issue
- I also removed all the external monitors connected
- Restarted the machine several times

Comment: Try a powered USB hub instead.

Comment: Thanks, Allan. I don't have that, but I will get that very soon.